# UIDocumentPickerViewController crashes after picking documents

Tags: ios, swift, file, ios13, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I'm currently working on, macOs 10.15 beta 2, Xcode 11 beta 2, iPadOS 13 beta 2 (iPad Air 2),

I have added UIDocumentPickerViewController as a child viewController in a tabview like this.

```
var controller : UIDocumentPickerViewController!
func addDocumentPickerController() {

    controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(
        documentTypes: ["public.png"], // choose your desired documents the user is allowed to select
        in: .import // choose your desired UIDocumentPickerMode
    )
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    controller.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top

    self.controller.view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalTo(topPadding ?? 0)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Now in delegates

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
}
```

this methods doesn't get called.

Only below error in console.

```
[TraitCollection] Class _UIRootPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
[TraitCollection] Class UIPopoverPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
[TraitCollection] Class _UISheetPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
[TraitCollection] Class UIPreviewPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
[DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
[DocumentManager] Remote view controller crashed with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}. Trying to relaunch.
```

Any idea on this is happening.

Comment: I added it in containerWiew. And it works fine. The same issue occurs even if I simply present UIDocumentPickerViewController.

Comment: Here is a simple document picker test project. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p803PickACloudSong/PickACloudSong/ViewController.swift

Comment: @matt actually the app doesn't crashes. Only UIDocumentPickerViewController crashes and loads again.

Comment: Maybe it has to be with the popover controller as you are in iPad, try adding this:
controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

Comment: @matt the Title clearly says UIDocumentPickerViewController crashes.

Comment: Ok. Did you run the test project?

Comment: Yes, and it does work

Comment: @matt the Test project doesn't work if I add 'picker.allowsMultipleSelection = true'

Comment: and you'll have to select multiple files

Comment: Hey, @matt any luck?